# Used Migration Assistant on Catalina, now all data is missing from original drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina, data-transfer, migration, migration-assistant

One of the computers a coworker was working on, a 2012 13" MBPU, required a data transfer to a 2015 13" MBPR. He set up Migration Assistant on both computers after hooking them up with a firewire cable and initiated the transfer. He left it to run over the weekend (Sat eve to Mon morn) and upon returning to the computer found it had not budged (~14000 files transferred). He quit Migration Assistant, went back into the OS, and re-initiated the transfer, this time using a USB to SATA cable with the OG 2.5" SSD outside of the case instead of firewire.

This time, Migration Assistant reflected ~53k files transferred before it halted and did not show signs of progress, so he decided to quit out of Migration Assistant again and use a Time Machine backup to transfer the data. However, when he quit M.A., the computer rebooted instead of kicking the OS back to the login screen. The Apple loading bar progressed to fill the whole bar, then hung on that screen for ~15m before he decided to restart the computer to resolve the hang.

Upon rebooting, he held down the OPT key to try and boot into the OG 2.5" SSD instead of the new SSD, and found that it gave him the No Entry sign.
At this point, he removed the OG SSD from the USB to SATA cable and plugged it internally into the original 13" 2012 MBPU, where he found it also gave him the No Entry sign. He grabbed a Mojave USB installer, booted into recovery mode on the original 13", and found that the OG SSD was being seen as having no data on it. It had the typical hierarchy:

> 2.5" SSD
>
> > Container disk
> >
> > > MacHD
> > >
> > > MacHD Data

but no data on the two OS partitions, besides around ~10GB on both.

The new 2015 13" MBPR continued to hang on the full loading bar upon multiple reboots, and he reinstalled Catalina on that one to find that no data had been transferred save for one Deleted User folder with the name of the User from the original 13" MPRU's 2.5" SSD, but with a '3' after it. Upon restoring it, he found there was nothing inside but a bunch of strange system files--no personal data, or the usual folder structure that you would expect inside a User Folder.

So here we are.

We've tried Repair Disk on the OG SSD to no avail, searching for more hidden files on the 13" MBPR's SSD, and reinstalling Catalina onto the OG SSD to see if the data was just undercover (it was not). We did, however, find that the OG User Folder was there where it should be in the Users folder (no number suffix), just with no data inside.

Any ideas on if/where that data could be located? No backups of any kind for the OG data.

Comment: Please say you have a Time Machine backup.... ***Please!***

Comment: I had a similar case 2 weeks ago: MacBook Air 2012 in Target Disk Mode (with a very old battery and probably impaired file system - I didn't check it because I was in a hurry) to MacBook Air 2018 migration (both Mojave). Migration stopped in the middle, so I canceled it. Checked the **source** after rebooting attached to another Mac because it didn't boot - only the /Users/main_user/ with ~10 GB (of maybe 50 GB User content) was remaining. System, Library etc. all gone. Nothing to repair, nothing to recover with DiskDrill... I didn't expect Migration Assistant to modify the **source device**.

Comment: I'm guessing you bolded source and source device to emphasize that terminology over my use of original/OG.

Comment: Has Migration Assistant traditionally utilized modifying the source device to transfer data? I would think copy/paste isn't inherently assuming much risk, but to use M.A. and roll the dice on it deleting, or otherwise misplacing data... seems like a warning or disclaimer of some sort is warranted. I've seen next to nothing on this issue online, though--mine seems to be the only report of this issue. Perhaps a newer OS issue/Firewire troubles, since I assume that's what you used w/TDM? Either way, I'm not very happy. Pissed would be a suitable adjective for how I felt earlier. >:(